# Customer data page not working

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7

After I have switch to `PHP7` my customer data is not working see screenshot https://gyazo.com/e469216e2970fc3c1f55f354a22a46f7 Can somebody tell me how I can fix it ?

The only error I see is :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of null(…)

Comment: First try to enable error reporting, then refresh cache, reload page and try to find the error in the page source.